# Arrays and Objects are being fetched and then reset to undefined. Using React/JavaScript/Json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am new to JavaScript and React and am building a weather app that allows the user to save locations to their profile and retrieve the forecast data relevant to that specific location.
I need to display a list of buttons that display the only the names of the locations saved by the user logged in.
Currently, I'm fetching locations, current profile, and then mapping through the locations that was returned by the fetch to match up the location id's to the foreign keys saved to the profile. Right now, all of my fetches return empty arrays and objects. However, if I edit the code and save it, my React app re-renders correctly and the console prints the correct data. When I refresh the page I'm back to empty arrays and objects.

Here's my ProfilesProvider:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const ProfileContext = createContext();

export const ProfileProvider = (props) => {
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([]);
  const [currentProfile, setCurrentProfile] = useState({});

  const getProfiles = () => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8088/profiles")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((theProfiles) => setProfiles(theProfiles))
      .then(console.log(profiles));
  };

  const getCurrentProfile = () => {
    let id = localStorage.getItem("weathernet_user");
    return fetch(`http://localhost:8088/profiles/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((theProfile) => {
        return setCurrentProfile(theProfile);
      })
      .then(console.log(currentProfile));
  };
```

Heres my LocationsProvider:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const LocationContext = createContext();

export const LocationProvider = (props) => {
  const apiURL = "http://localhost:8088";
  const locationsURL = apiURL + "/locations";
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState([]);

  let id = localStorage.getItem("weathernet_user");

  const getLocations = () => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8088/locations")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setLocations);
  };

  const addLocation = (locationObj) => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8088/locations", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(locationObj),
    }).then(getLocations());
  };
```

And here's the module where I'm implementing the code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { LocationContext } from "./LocationsProvider";
import { ProfileContext } from "../profiles/ProfilesProvider";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Locations.css";

export const LocationList = () => {
  const { locations, getLocations, deleteLocation } =
    useContext(LocationContext);
  const { profiles, getProfiles, currentProfile, getCurrentProfile } =
    useContext(ProfileContext);
  const [profile, setCurrentProfile] = useState({});
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState({});
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(true);
  const [buttonList, setButtonList] = useState([]);

  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      getLocations(),
      getProfiles(),
      getCurrentProfile(),
      setCurrentProfile(),
    ]).then(() => {
      console.log(currentProfile);
      setButtonList(locationResults);
      console.log(buttonList);
      console.log(locationResults);
    });
  }, []);

  const locationResults = (currentProfile.savedCityId || []).map((cityId) => {
    return locations.find((location) => location.id === cityId);
  });
```

I didn't include the lower half of the module because it's where im returning a form and I didn't want to clutter up the question too much

Comment: It's hard to guess what exactly goes wrong. If I were you I would debug a little bit more with DevTools of your browser. Specifically, the "Network" tab, since your requests return different values. Since there is only one request with a parameter (`http://localhost:8088/profiles/${id}`) I would look there first. Check if there is a correct `id` used.

Comment: @stefanowiczp Sorry, I was not specific enough... I have done this. The network tab indicates successful fetches for locations, profiles, and currentProfile (the request you mention above) initiated by their respective providers. They all return correct data.

Comment: Creating a codesandbox for this would be helpful.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer creating one currently

Comment: @ChrisFarmer One is created, but accessing localStorage to get the user id is denied within codesandbox and I'm not sure how big of an issue that will be (Sorry Ive only been coding three months I don't know much)